# How to break a event flow form an Observer and redirect to the same page in Magento 2?

Tags: event-observer, redirect

How can I break a flow when some condition is true? Let's say the customer is writing a review for the product `https://url/review/product/post/id/2/` and when the user presses the save butto some condition should be tested and if true the save process should not continue, and the user should be redirected to the same page with a error message ('your message could not be saved ....'.

For the moment I have the following code inside the observer:

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

        if($sometest === true){
            $this->messageManager->addError(__("you have an error in your string"));
        }
        //Avoid save and redirect to the same page
    }
```

What should I use in order to break the save process and redirect the user to the same page?

Answer (score 0):

### Edited:

I am not sure why `review_controller_product_init_before` . It is very strange to me. I have  tried  with  redirection using `Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory` and want to failed.

So, for your case, you can use  direct using

observer over `controller_action_predispatch_review_product_post`

OR, You can  create redirection  using plugin over `Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post:execute`

I have chosen the observer for your requirement.

**Observer Class look Like:**

```
<?php

namespace {VendorName}\{ModuelName}\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RedirectfromPostObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    private $actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context
     */
    private $context;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    private $redirect;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
            \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $manager,
            \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
    ) {

        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->manager = $manager;
        $this->actionFlag = $actionFlag;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {

        $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        $currentActionName = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getActionName();
        $nickname = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParam('nickname', false);
        $title = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParam('title', false);
        $detail = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParam('detail', false);
        $ratings = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', false);

        $sometest = true;
        if ($sometest === true) {
            $this->manager->addErrorMessage(__("you have an error in your string %1", 
                    $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParam('nickname')));
            $controllerAction->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
            $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            $this->redirect->redirect($controllerAction->getResponse(), $this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Amt,  this line is generating an error $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);  // Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Source class "\Exercise\Two\Observer\Result" for "Exercise\Two\Observer\ResultFactory" generation does not exist.

Comment: In fact there is two choices: 1 -  use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; and we can use the ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT inside create or 2 - this dirty opition $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create('redirect'); At least will not break the process. I have used the first one. It is grabbing the referece URL.